# How to implement Java Rest-Assured API authentication using the uid key and secret key to retrieve token?

Tags: java, api, rest, token, rest-assured

I am familiar with rest-assured, but now I have to validate a POST API request call that requires authentication. Developers provided the uid key and secret key to retrieve the token from the server and then use it for the POST API request using rest-assured.
I have tried a couple of options with no success. Am I supposed to use oauth-signpost ? Any help or guidance is really appreciated. Thanks

```
information provided by dev
uid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
secret: wwwwwwwwwwwwwww
POST /api/v1/gardners.json

{
"gardner":  {
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "password": "12345678",
  "password_confirmation": "12345678",
  "phone": "555-555-5555",
  "status": "active",
  "address": "Street Name",
  "zipcode": "99999",
  "add_state": "CA",
  "city": "Los Angeles",
  "region_id": "2",
  "shirt_size": "S",
  "payment_info": "some info",
  "birthday": "date",
  "inactive_date": "datetime",
  "certification_date" : "datetime",
  "calendar_base_id" : 5,
  "rating" : 5
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with how Rest Assured does this, but there must be a mechanism for authentication.  The first thing to find out is what kind of authentication is in place.  Is it 'Basic' or 'Digest'?  If it's just based on header values or cookies, then you just need to set the header value or cookie with the right values and make sure that the Rest Assured client uses these when making requests.

First you need to understand the authentication that is in place, and then look at the Rest Assured docs for how to do this.

For me, I prefer to work at a lower level and I use the Apache HttpClient, which lets me configure everything in relation to communication protocol, authentication, and header and cookie values.

Answer (score 0):

I use an Object to provide the details for authentication.  Then I use that object to configure the client builder.

```
public class AuthenticationConfiguration {
  public enum AuthenticationType {
    Basic, Digest
  }

  private AuthenticationType authenticationType = AuthenticationType.Basic;

  public AuthenticationType getAuthenticationType() {
    return authenticationType;
  }

  private String userName;

  private String password;

  public AuthenticationConfiguration(final AuthenticationType authenticationType,
      final String userName, final String password) {

    this.authenticationType = authenticationType;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setAuthenticationType(AuthenticationType authenticationType) {
    this.authenticationType = authenticationType;
  }

  public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }
}

// Create an HttpClient with the given custom dependencies and
// configuration.
final HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();

if (authenticationConfig != null) {
  // Use custom credentials provider if necessary.
  // See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/tutorial/html/authentication.html
  final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

  final UsernamePasswordCredentials creds =
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials(authenticationConfig.getUserName(),
          authenticationConfig.getPassword());

  credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
  clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

  final RegistryBuilder<AuthSchemeProvider> registryBuilder = RegistryBuilder.create();

  if (authenticationConfig.getAuthenticationType() == AuthenticationType.Basic) {
    registryBuilder.register(AuthSchemes.BASIC, new BasicSchemeFactory());
    requestConfigBuilder.setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.BASIC));

  } else if (authenticationConfig.getAuthenticationType() == AuthenticationType.Digest) {
    registryBuilder.register(AuthSchemes.DIGEST, new DigestSchemeFactory());
    requestConfigBuilder.setTargetPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.DIGEST));
  }

  clientBuilder.setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(registryBuilder.build());
}
```